# UIAlertView in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

What is the standard size of UIAlertView for ipad application?
it's same as iPhone?
if anybody has some idea please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

They are identical in terms of pixels. However, they differ in physical size because of the difference in screen resolution between the two devices. The iPad version appears about 20% larger in terms of area. In both cases, the alert is about 275px wide.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, the width of an alert view's frame is 284 points and the height is 141 points.